# Perl array shortcuts

Tags: arrays, perl

Is it possible to create an array of string variables in perl without having to specify each single string that goes in the array? Like by using the ".." shortcut for letters and numbers.

For example:

```
$v1 = "hey";
$v2 = "hello";
$v3 = "bye";
$v4 = "welcome";

@f = ("$v1" .. "$v4");
```

so that print $f[2]; would equal "bye"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be - but should probably not - be solved by using `no strict 'refs'`. And also coincidentally `no strict 'vars'`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

{
    no strict 'vars';
    $v1 = "hey";
    $v2 = "hello";
    $v3 = "bye";
    $v4 = "welcome";

    no strict 'refs';
    my @f = map ${'v'.$_},1..4;
    print Dumper \@f;
}
```

**Output: (sans warnings)**

```
$VAR1 = [
          'hey',
          'hello',
          'bye',
          'welcome'
        ];
```

We need `no strict 'vars'` because the variables we actually need to refer to are (really) named `$main::v1` etc. We can actually get around the need for `no strict 'vars'` by using the full designation. And if you are not using strict at all, this is not even an issue. Though not using `strict` is about as smart as solving your cars engine problems by putting a sticker over the warning lamps: It won't save your engine breaking down.

Should you do it? Hardly. There are always ways around it. But it's not horribly wrong to do it this way, assuming you don't go overboard with cheating like this.

The **proper** way is to instead of using `$v1`, ... `$v1000`, using `$v[0]`, ... `$v[1000]`. That is, assigning the values to an array right away.

Comment: Of course! Assigning the values to an array at first. Very clever, I hadn't thought of this! This solves the problem and there is no need to use eval or play around with the strict vars. Thank you all guys. You are all very bright and your responses were very helpful and insightful. Sorry I misunderstood the ones who were saying why not start with an array. This is probably what you meant

Answer (score 2):

I'm not thrilled about the approach, but you could do this:

```
$v1 = "hey";
$v2 = "hello";
$v3 = "bye";
$v4 = "welcome";

@f = map{eval "\$v$_"}1..4;
```

Comment: I accepted this response, which is a clever use of eval, but I am worried about security risk in using this method. Any thoughts?

Comment: There shouldn't be a risk, unless the user is also defining the names of the variables. I have a similar answer in the works, coming soon

Comment: If `$v1` etc are `my` variables (and they should be) then actually I think this method is best. If they are `our` variables (as your example shows) then you can get them via symbolic ref (temporarily doing `no strict 'refs';` Then again, toolic is probably correct, you really ought to use a hash, then you can get the names or values at will.

Comment: I agree with Joel's point above and with toolic's comment.  My answer is an attempt at answering your question literally -- in practice I tend not to eval a string together to build a varname, just to get a var value.

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you mean ?

```
my @v = qw/hey hello bye welcome/;

print join "\n", @v;
```

When this `ARRAY` is created, you can access any item with

```
print $v[0];
```

where `0` is the index of the `ARRAY` : *hey* in our case.

Comment: No, $v1 to $v4 are filled by other users in the script. I want to be able to get all these data in an array lower in the script without having to type them again. THere are several variables and several arrays, which is why I am asking this question, since it would reduce my code.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could write a procedure to do this using eval, but why use $v1, $v2 in the first place? Why not start with an array?

Or perhaps, depending on what you really need to do, use something like

`@f = qw(hey hello bye welcome);`

Comment: $v1 to $v4 are completed by other users with very little knowledge of perl. I want to be able to get these variables in an array in a lower part of the script without typing them again. I simplified, but it is more something like $v1 to $v35 and several arrays ($w1 to $w40), etc.

Comment: "Completed by other users" - if they have something like `$v1 = [add data here]; $v2 = [add data here]`, how about changing that to `@v[1] = [add data here]; @v[2] = [add data here];`?

Comment: Ooops, in the above, the correct syntax for array variables is `$[1], $[2]`, etc